# _OBJC_CLASS_$_Crittercism - ibCrittercism_v3_5_1.a

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

We are updating old app and we run into problem when trying to simulate it in anything higher than iPhone 5 ... so, from iPhone S5 we have this issue...

```
> ld: warning: ignoring file .../CrittercismSDK/libCrittercism_v3_5_1.a,
> missing required architecture x86_64 in file
> .../CrittercismSDK/libCrittercism_v3_5_1.a (3 slices) Undefined
> symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crittercism",
> referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
> 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What part of the error isn't crystal clear to you?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to this, Warren's answer helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What it says. You have an old Crittercism SDK which doesn't have a 64 bit simulator slice.

You can potentially remove x86_64 from the valid architectures list or even better upgrade your Crittercism library as the latest version seems to have a [x86_64 build](http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/Unity-SDK-size).

Comment: Thanks a lot Warren! I really appreciate you answer. I have downloaded the new Crittercism and all is good now. I'm new to this ;) 
All the best PS: I I would vote your answer, but I haven't got the "stackoverflow's reputation" yet.